# Are the prepositions "of", "on" and "about" interchangeable when used after the noun "idea"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if the prepositions *of*, *on* and *about* interchangeable when used after the noun *idea*? For example:

> The boss has a new idea **of** how to improve the working conditions at the office.
>
> The boss has a new idea **on** how to improve the working conditions at the office.
>
> The boss has a new idea **about** how to improve the working conditions at the office.

Comment: **About** would be the most idiomatic here - however, we can say "Sitting on the beach all day is not my idea of a holiday" (not what I would want from a holiday).

Comment: They have *a thought* / *thoughts* **on**... You can *impose* your idea(s) **on** someone.